# Getting div to float over text

Tags: css

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/nehaB/

But for some reason, when the dropdown is activated, it does not float over the text in the p tag.

How can I get it to float over the text instead of the dropdown moving the text away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/nehaB/2/

What I did is to add `position:relative;z-index:1;` for `.menu` and `position:absolute` for content `div`